# How to find a freeze due to a recursive bug

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

There is a code trying to do the following task:

> It is necessary to place the knights on the chessboard and determine which is the largest number of such pieces can be placed on the 8x8 board (the knight beats any piece located two squares horizontally or vertically and one square diagonally).

Here is the code, but it constantly freezes, I suspect that it is recursively hanging somewhere, but I don't know how to fix it. I cannot use loop operators and the Prog operator.

```
(defun place-knight (board row col count)
  (let ((size (array-dimension board 0)))
    (when (and (<= 0 row (- size 1))
               (<= 0 col (- size 1))
               (null (aref board row col)))
      (setf (aref board row col) t)
      (when (= count (* size size))
        (setf (aref board row col) nil)
        t)
      (let ((moves '((1 . 2) (1 . -2) (-1 . 2) (-1 . -2)
                     (2 . 1) (2 . -1) (-2 . 1) (-2 . -1))))
        (some (lambda (move)
                (place-knight board
                              (+ row (car move))
                              (+ col (cdr move))
                              (if (= count (* size size))1
                                  (1+ count))))
              moves))
      (setf (aref board row col) nil))))

      (defun knights-tour ()
  (let ((size 8)
        (board (make-array (list 8 8) :initial-element nil))
        (max-knights 0))
    (labels ((search-board (row col count)
               (when (<= row (- size 1))
                 (when (place-knight board row col count)
                   (incf max-knights))
                 (search-board (if (= col (- size 1))(1+ row)
                                   row)
                               (if (= col (- size 1))0                   
                                   (1+ col))
                               (if (= count (* size size))1
                                   (1+ count))))))
      (search-board 0 0 1))
    max-knights))
```

Comment: What does it mean "it freezes"? Does it work on a smaller board?

Comment: `place-knight` never returns anything "truthy". Test it on its own first.

Comment: Yeah, like MOLBDNILO says, it makes sense to have some test cases for individual functions and see if the expected result is returned...

Comment: Inside PLACE-KNIGHT, you're calling SOME on a list defined in PLACE-KNIGHT using a lambda that calls PLACE-KNIGHT. Maybe you could define MOVES outside the function, then use simple recursion in PLACE-KNIGHT instead of nesting applicative operator SOME that recursively call PLACE-KNIGHT.

Answer (score -1):

```
(defun max-knights (n)
  "Returns the maximum number of knights that can be placed on an NxN chessboard
   without any of them attacking each other."
  (let ((num-squares (* n n)))
    (if (evenp n)
        (/ num-squares 2)
        (/ (1+ num-squares) 2))))

CL-USER> (max-knights 8)
32
```